# How to achieve the robustness while detecting features from a continuous video stream

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection

I have been working with object detection from a video but the problem is, I cannot detect the same features in two consecutive frames.

I am using SURF with Brute Force Matcher and knnMatch. Ratio has been set to 0.5 for good matching

Answer (score 1):

I think if you put in your code and the version of the OpenCV, it might be little easier to deal with your problem. The newest version of OpenCV comes with better detection and tracking algorithms (you can go through this) http://www.learnopencv.com/object-tracking-using-opencv-cpp-python/.